# how to change the shortcuts in Intellij idea ultimate?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, vuejs2, onchange, shortcut

I want change a few shortcuts like `shift+F6` (for Renaming and Refactoring) to `F2` (move to next warning).
I know there are few questions on Stack OverFlow But none of them meets my Requirement
No links or just answer If any one knows here
I also have visited the official Docs There I found `ctrl+alt+s` command

Comment: ctrl+alt+s but could not found it there

Comment: You can try using "Find Actions by Shortcut" in Keymap settings to find the needed option - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-keymap.html#21f04ebd. Is it what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps (with pictures) that show what I've done so far to change the key:

1. Searched by key which obviously failed:
   [image]
2. Then I searched by Refactor and also it failed:
   [image]
3. But then I tried by Using command name like rename, the First item appears with command was my target. I changed it to F2 but it kept making warnings. So I added a Mouse Event the at Right Click It'll Rename any File or Folder:
   [image]